# Cyclic subgroups and groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Im trying to answer this question:

part (a): Describe the cyclic subgroup $\left\langle \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle $ in $\mathbb{R^*}$.

part (b): Describe the cyclic group $\left\langle \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle $ in $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm not sure what they mean by describe but I believe for part (a) and part (b):

they are both order infinity.

Anyone can help me answer this question?

Comment: I imagine that you are supposed to write the set of elements that corresponds to each subgroup.

Comment: Yes, both are infinite groups. But these are also cyclic groups. So you can write down the general form of an element in these subgroups. I think that's what it means.

Comment: Would it be $(\frac{1}{2})^n$ for the cyclic group and I'm not sure for the subgroup but I think its the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: think about the following two functions:

$f: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(k) = \dfrac{k}{2}$ (this is for part(b), where the group operation is +).

$g: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb R$ given by $g(k) = \dfrac{1}{2^k}$ (this is for part (a), where the group operation is $\ast$).